# Mocking exception strategy through munit in mule

Tags: mule

We are having an exception strategy in one of our mule flow as follows

```
<flow name="myFlow">
   .........
   .........
   outboubd-call
   .........
   <catch-exception-strategy>
       <exception-strategy ref="myOwnExceptionStrategy" />
   </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

While we are throwing exception by mocking outbound using munit ,It enters into catch-exception-strategy .
I am also mocking the  as follows

```
  whenMessageProcessor("exception-strategy").thenReturn(muleMessageWithPayload("OK"));
```

But instead of returning the specified mule message, it is actually going into the referred exception strategy(which I can clearly see through logs).

I also tried the following

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("ref","myOwnExceptionStrategy");
whenMessageProcessor("exception-strategy").withAttributes(map).thenReturn(muleMessageWithPayload("OK"));
```

Unfortunately, above approach is also not fruitful .

Suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern that might help is to put the flow logic within the exception strategy inside a sub-flow, like so:

```
<catch-exception-strategy name="myOwnExceptionStrategy">
    <flow-ref name="handleMyOwnExceptionMessage" />
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

You can then mock the flow that the exception strategy references.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock exception strategies in munit as they are not message processors.

Also, If you're expecting an exception, can't you just assert the correct exception is thrown? Or the correct error response is returned etc?

Comment: "Also, If you're expecting an exception, can't you just assert the correct exception is thrown? Or the correct error response is returned etc?"

I think the goal is to make sure the correct exception strategy is invoked when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the answer above , exception-strategies are not message processors. If you observe the new mule studio released in jan 2015 they clear differentiated the flows as "source,process, error handling.

As of now munit doesn't support thing,in future may be.